# Laravel parameterBag as array issues when inserting

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to insert mass data but i get this error when i iterate through the request:

> Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError Cannot use
>   object of type Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag as array

Request example:

```
    request: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag {#52 ▼
        #parameters: array:4 [▼
        "_token" => "Z1sF2K5LHU1bsQ4l3JRaOLCTQDmJ47qakigmrfI5"
        "name" => "Rousaddasd 1"
        "secsaddsans" => array:1 [▼
            "secsdfs1" => array:2 [▼
            "name" => "Sectdfs 1"

            ]
        ]
        "submit" => "Submit"
        ]
    }
```

Loop to go through the request and insert:

```
$abc = new abc;
$abc->create(['user_id' => 1, 'name' => $request->name, 'description' => 'test description']);
foreach($request as $item){
    $asd = new asd;
    $asd->name = $item['name'];
    $asd->description = 'test description';
    $abc->asds()->create([$asd]);


}
```

Im adding some data "inline" because i didnt handle them in the form yet, thats why the added duration and duration_unit for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use $request as array like this:

```
$request = $request->all();
```

And loop like:

```
foreach($request['sections'] as $item) {
   ....

   foreach($item['exercises'] as $item2) {
     ....
   }

}
```

Comment: That seems to let it go further, but now i get a problem with this like "$section->name = $item['name'];" as Illegal string offset 'name' even tho it should be correct or am i wrong?

Comment: Okay the corrected foreach did it, is it because trhe wrong "depth" was selected without the ['sections']?
And another thing, why am i missing a routine__id here: $routine->sections()->create([$section]);  ? it should get "auto" assigned by $reuqest-sections()->... ?

Comment: if the question is still relevant ... It's depending on tables relations in you DB.. maybe $section->save(); $routine->sections()->save($section) or $routine->sections()->attach($section->id)
Method "create" use only for creating model (without relations), for example, you can use $section = Section::create(['name'=>'name','description'=>'some text'])